# How to specify lm model matrix

Tags: r, lm

I have measurements obtained from 2 groups where each group has the same 3 levels.
Here's my example `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(measurement = c(rnorm(10,1,1),rnorm(10,0.75,1),rnorm(10,1.25,1),
                rnorm(10,0.5,1),rnorm(10,1.75,1),rnorm(10,0.25,1)),
                group = as.factor(c(rep("a",30),rep("b",30))),
                level = as.factor(rep(c(rep("x",10),rep("y",10),rep("z",10)),2)))
```

I'm interested in quantifying how `measurement` in each `level` is affected by `group`.

I guess a linear model (`lm`) is the appropriate approach for this, where the `group:level` interaction terms capture the effects I'm interested in.

Is there a way to specify an `lm` that will only compute these interaction terms: `groupb:levelx`, `groupb:levely`, and `groupb:levelz`? I believe this tells me how each `level` is affected by `group` "b" (relative to `group` "a"), which I think is what I'm interested in.

The closest I got is:

```
lm(measurement ~ 0 + group * level - group, data = df)
```

But that still computes the effects of `levelx`, `levely`, and `levelz`, which I'm not interested in.

Comment: The question seems a bit unclear. group 'b' is relative to group 'a' and vice versa since this is a binary variable. You cannot change that. You either exclude records that contain group='a' and run the regression only on group==b without using group in the model or you use the variable as it is. Then if you use lm one of the levels will be left out and all the rest will be relative to that. You also seem to introduce interactions in your lm but do you really need these?

Comment: Just to make clear that my answer below makes sense :-) The statistical equivalent of "quantifying how measurement in each level is affected by group", in my opinion, is : For each level x,y,z is there any difference between the (average) measurements of a and b? If there is, is it statistically significant?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my intention. Thanks a lot

Comment: @AntoniosK, my actual measurements are proportions, which include zeros (but not ones). Any idea what model will fit that best? (I'm aware that this is not an SO question per se hence the comment)

Comment: I guess the zeros you have mean 0% and not a flag that shows "not success", right? So, you should be able to go back before you calculated those percentages and have as values 1/0 (success/not success; binary variable) and apply a logistic regression model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Lyzander mentioned above you should clarify a bit more what you want. Based on what you said "how measurement is affected by group "b" (relative to group "a") for each level", I guess there are 3 simple ways to do that.

```
df <- data.frame(measurement = c(rnorm(10,1,1),rnorm(10,0.75,1),rnorm(10,1.25,1),
                                 rnorm(10,0.5,1),rnorm(10,1.75,1),rnorm(10,0.25,1)),
                 group = as.factor(c(rep("a",30),rep("b",30))),
                 level = as.factor(rep(c(rep("x",10),rep("y",10),rep("z",10)),2)))


library(dplyr)

#### calculate stats (mean values) ---------------------------------------------
df %>% group_by(level, group) %>% summarise(MeanMeasurement = mean(measurement))

#     level  group MeanMeasurement
#    (fctr) (fctr)           (dbl)
# 1      x      a       1.6708659
# 2      x      b       0.8487751
# 3      y      a       0.7977769
# 4      y      b       1.4209206
# 5      z      a       1.5484668
# 6      z      b      -0.3244225

#### build a model for each level ---------------------------------------------
summary(lm(measurement ~ group  , data = df[df$level=="x",]))

# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   1.6709     0.3174   5.264 5.27e-05 ***
#   groupb       -0.8221     0.4489  -1.831   0.0837 .


summary(lm(measurement ~ group  , data = df[df$level=="y",]))

# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
# (Intercept)   0.7978     0.2565   3.111  0.00604 **
#   groupb        0.6231     0.3627   1.718  0.10295


summary(lm(measurement ~ group  , data = df[df$level=="z",]))

# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   1.5485     0.3549   4.363 0.000375 ***
#   groupb       -1.8729     0.5019  -3.731 0.001528 **



## build a model only with interactions ------------------------------------------
summary(lm(measurement ~ group : level , data = df))

# Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
# Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)    -0.3244     0.3123  -1.039 0.303452    
# groupa:levelx   1.9953     0.4416   4.518 3.43e-05 ***
#   groupb:levelx   1.1732     0.4416   2.657 0.010354 *  
#   groupa:levely   1.1222     0.4416   2.541 0.013951 *  
#   groupb:levely   1.7453     0.4416   3.952 0.000227 ***
#   groupa:levelz   1.8729     0.4416   4.241 8.76e-05 ***
#   groupb:levelz       NA         NA      NA       NA
```

If you check the stats (1st approach) and the models' coefficients you'll see that all those 3 approaches agree with each other.

I'd go with the 2nd approach as it is the only one that gives you info about whether a difference of `group` (a vs b) within a `level` is statistically significant or not. 1st approach just reports means. 3rd approach includes p values but they correspond to comparisons with a baseline interaction value and not to comparisons between groups a and b.

You mentioned "ONLY compute these interaction terms: groupb:levelx, groupb:levely, and groupb:levelz" which means that you won't get the other 3 interactions of a and x,y,z. In other words you force your model to include those 3 interactions.

You can do that manually like this

```
df <- data.frame(measurement = c(rnorm(10,1,1),rnorm(10,0.75,1),rnorm(10,1.25,1),
                                 rnorm(10,0.5,1),rnorm(10,1.75,1),rnorm(10,0.25,1)),
                 group = as.factor(c(rep("a",30),rep("b",30))),
                 level = as.factor(rep(c(rep("x",10),rep("y",10),rep("z",10)),2)))

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(interactions = paste0(group,":",level),
         interactions = ifelse(group=="a","a",interactions)) -> df2

summary(lm(measurement ~ interactions, data = df2))

# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)       0.9318     0.1831   5.089 4.36e-06 ***
#   interactionsb:x  -0.7803     0.3662  -2.131  0.03752 *  
#   interactionsb:y   0.2747     0.3662   0.750  0.45638    
# interactionsb:z  -1.1367     0.3662  -3.104  0.00299 **
```

but now the other 3 interactions are combined and every time you compare each one of your 3 interactions (b:x, b:y, b:z) with the general group a. You don't compare a vs. b within x,y and z but you compare x vs. y vs. z within group b.

Comment: You might consider the model with `measurement ~ level + group:level`, I think this highlights the contrast OP is asking for.

Comment: @Gregor I thought about this point of view, but I got confused and that's why I asked for clarifications. Not sure if he wants `levely`, `levelz` and `levelx` (baseline) that this model includes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the discussion. I hope my updated post clarifies what I'm interested in. As @AntoniosK noted, measurement ~ level + group:level, which is equivalent to measurement ~ 0 + group * level - group, still computes me levely, levelz and levelx, which I'm not interested in.

Comment: @user1701545 I think what you ask is not possible as the interpretation is not what you want/describe. When there are 6 interactions and you want your model to include 3 of those, then the other 3 should be combined together and create the base line. I'll update my answer to explain a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this sentence: "Is there a way to specify an lm that will only compute these interaction terms: groupb:levelx, groupb:levely, and groupb:levelz?", I think you just want:

```
lm( measurement ~ level +0, subset = group=="b", data = df)
```